# html input range step as an array of values

Tags: html, html-input

I've been playing around with the `input type=range` for the first time, and ideally I'd like to set the step value to an array of values. I looked over the spec and I see the possibility for a datalist but it seams the data list is only used for highlight values in a range, so to speak, but not setting the values in the range.

So, something like this (ideally without a jQuery plugin, etc.):

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" step="1,3,5,10,20">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step-scale), the values for step can be "any" or a positive floating-point number. That's it.

> The step attribute, if specified, must either have a value that is a
>   valid floating-point number that parses to a number that is greater
>   than zero, or must have a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive
>   match for the string "any".

Comment: That was my take on it as well. Nice to have some validation though. Thanks!!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but that link was 404, I think this is the updated url https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#range-state-(type=range)

Comment: @AllisonC Thanks for the heads up. I'm updating the link and adding some text from the spec.

Answer (score 64):

You can achieve this by storing the values in an array and using the slider as the indexer for the array. This example will step through 1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 as you slide.

```js
const values = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100];

const input = document.getElementById('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');

input.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};

// set the default value
input.oninput();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="6" step="1">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please help, how to do this inline in the html like oninput="function(...)", I can't use this because my data is in a foreach loop, and I am not sure how to run this script from within the loop, with the relevant values array.

Answer (score 7):

Karmacon's answer works just fine, but don't forget to add the attribute `aria-valuetext` to the input element. It will help screen readers read out the correct value.

MDN provides a good example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_slider_role#Example_2_Text_Values

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Having the next input:

```
    <input id="currentTimeInput" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="60" oninput="toggleSteps(this);" list=mapsettings>
    <datalist id=mapsettings>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>60</option>
    </datalist>
```

Here is my function to change the steps by 1 (0-10) and 10 (10-60)

```
function toggleSteps(element) {
    var minutes = parseInt(element.value);
    if (minutes > 10) {
        element.step = 10;
    } else {
        element.step = 1;
    }
}
```