# Is it possible to have predefined steps on an HTML5 range slider?

Tags: html

I have an html5 range input element and would like the available steps to be 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 80, 100, 120, 150.

I have an idea to possibly set the min to 50, max to 150 and change the step value using jquery based on the current value. My first instinct is that this wouldn't be the most elegant solution (assuming it would work in the first place).

Any ideas as to what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300767/html-input-range-step-as-an-array-of-values

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Try something like this:

```html
<label for="rangeSlider">Slider</label>
<input type="range" min="50" max="150" value="70" id="rangeSlider" step="5" list="rangeList">
<datalist id="rangeList">
     <option>50</option>
     <option>55</option>
     <option>60</option>
     <option>65</option>
     <option>70</option>
     <option>80</option>
        <option>100</option>
        <option>120</option>
        <option>150</option>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: The slider seems to snap to the listed options, but it's still possible to select values in between the steps

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @dovelce answer, to make it snap to the closest value, you can add this jquery

```
   let counts = [];
   jQuery('#rangeList option').each(function() {
         counts.push(jQuery(this).val());
   });
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#rangeSlider').on('change', function(){
             let goal = jQuery(this).val();
             var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
             });
             jQuery(this).val(closest);
        });
   });
```