# How to change input type="range" =>step value based on condition ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change input type="range" =>step value based on condition ?

like i want  :Difference: 200 250 350 450 all the way to 1150, 1200

```
<input id="years" type="range" value="200" min="200" max="1200" />
```

First value is 200..then its increase by 50...after that its increase by 100...(its look like : 250..350...1150...)

Look What I have tried...But not getting proper output

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

                $('#years').on('input change', function() {

                    var
                        element = $('#years'),
                        value = element.val(),
                        step;

                    /* 
                        Map your rules 
                    */
                    if (value <=250) {


                        step = 50;
                    }
                    else {

                        step = 100;   
                    }

                    element.attr('step', step);

                    $('#value').text(value);
                    $('#step').text(step);
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Current value: <span id="value"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            Current step: <span id="step"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="width:500px">
            <input id="years" type="range" value="200" min="200" max="1200" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

            <input id="years" type="range" value="200" min="200" max="1200" />
```

Comment: This answer could be exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300767/html-input-range-step-as-an-array-of-values/31586347#31586347 (you'll have to adapt the values and the steps to your needs of course)

Comment: thanks Connum I got solution! thanks again man !

Comment: Great, good to hear! :)

Comment: I just added my comment as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be exactly what you are looking for:
[html input range step as an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300767/html-input-range-step-as-an-array-of-values/31586347#31586347)
(you'll have to adapt the values and the steps to your needs of course)